# How to use ckeditor in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, ckeditor, laravel-5.8

I'm creating a new Blog web application using laravel. In this app in need an editor to create blog posts so I use `ckeditor` for this.

I have used the official `ckeditor` documentation to install and setup the ckeditor but it is not show the editor in my textarea.

**This is the script I used**

```js
<script src="/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('article-ckeditor');
</script>
```

**This is implementing ckeditor**

```js
<div class="form-group">
    {{Form::label('body', 'Body')}}
    {{Form::textarea('body', $post->body, ['id' => 'article-ckeditor', 'class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Body Text'])}}
</div>
```

**Here I found some error in console log**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)    (ckeditor.js:1)

Uncaught ReferenceError: CKEDITOR is not defined at create:108
```

**After run the** `php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor` **command i got more new errors.**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null           (ckeditor.js:326 )
    at b (ckeditor.js:326)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:322)
    at a.h (ckeditor.js:11)
    at a.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fire (ckeditor.js:14)
    at a.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:13)
    at a.window.CKEDITOR.window.CKEDITOR.dom.CKEDITOR.editor.CKEDITOR.editor.fireOnce (ckeditor.js:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (ckeditor.js:252)
    at g (ckeditor.js:233)
    at Object.load (ckeditor.js:233)
```

I'm creating a blogging app so I need an editor but it's not working and I can't solve this because it's not show any errors. The whole application is working property except this editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error it seems that the `ckeditor.js` file is not loading.

The official documentation of [UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor) says you should publish the resources via this command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=ckeditor
```

After that command you should have this file: `your_project_path/public/vendor/unisharp/laravel-ckeditor/ckeditor.js`.

**Update**: The last error (`Cannot read property 'unselectable' of null`) seems to be a known [issue](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-ckeditor/issues/30) of ckeditor with the default laravel `app.js`, they recommend to remove `defer` from the line loading `app.js` in the template `app.blade.php`:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: after run the command I got more errors in console and also in the app, textarea is not shown, before i run the command textarea i shown in the app now its not. check the question for those errors @dparoli

Comment: I updated my answer, but I cannot follow through all the problems of your code: I answered the original question and I gave you hints for the other error. Please accept and upvote my answer, if you have furthers errors open new questions with the relevant code.